# Why does for(;;) never terminate?

Tags: javascript

I always wondered why `for(;;)` acts like a `while(true)`. For loops run as long as the condition in the middle is true. It looks like here the condition is `''`, 0 chars long. `Boolean('')` clearly evaluates to false. So why does this run at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for):

> ```
> for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
> ```

Where `condition` is:

> An expression to be evaluated before each loop iteration. If this expression evaluates to true, statement is executed. This conditional test is optional. **If omitted, the condition always evaluates to true.** If the expression evaluates to false, execution skips to the first expression following the for construct.

Note that

```
Boolean('')
```

is passing an *empty string* to `Boolean`, which is not the same as what's being done in the `for` condition (where there's *nothing at all* in the `condition`).

If there *does* exist anything at all in `condition` (such as the empty string), then it's coerced to a `Boolean`. For example, `''` evaluates to `false`, so no iterations run:

```js
for (; '';) {
  console.log('iteration');
}
console.log('done');
```

Comment: The spec you quoted already tells us that the coercion to the boolean isn't the key here, though. The quoted spec just *defines* that an omitted condition evaluates to true.

Comment: Right, I was just distinguishing the difference between `; '' ;` and `;;`, which OP was confused about

Answer (score 1):

Really interesting question! If we [take a look at the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), it appears that all 3 possible arguments, initialization, condition, and final expression, are optional.

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression]) {...}
```

Initialization doesn't really matter if it's omitted, as it's just there for convenience to declare a locally-scoped variable.

Omitting the final expression also doesn't matter much, as it's just there for convenience, to do things like increment your counter variable and whatnot.

Interestingly, however, if the *condition* is omitted, the condition always evaluates to true. This is somewhat counter-intuitive, in my opinion!

So the key is the omission of condition. *sunglasses*

That means the loop conditional check always evaluates to true, so it will keep looping forever unless someone puts a stop to the madness.

Comment: `This is somewhat counter-intuitive` - that may be, but note that it is a very old tradition, even predating C

Comment: Gotta love ancient traditions! :p Thanks for the cool tid-bit @hanshenrik

Comment: Counter-intuitive indeed! I guess it's impossible to change tradition...